# Why is the default behavior in Rust to perform a move on assignment rather than just create another "reference" to the value?

Tags: rust

In Rust if you do the following:

```
let v1 = String::from("hello");
let v2 = v1;
println!("{}", v1);
```

You will get a compiler error because `=` in Rust performs a move, rather than a copy or a "share".

I was reading [this article](https://www.apress.com/us/blog/all-blog-posts/assignment-semantics/15805464) where it discusses this in more detail:

> But there is a bigger problem, regarding deallocation. If share semantics was used, both `v1` and `v2` would own the single data buffer, and so when they are deallocated, the same heap buffer would be deallocated twice. A buffer cannot be allocated twice, without causing memory corruption and consequently program malfunction. To solve this problem, the languages that use share semantics do not deallocate memory at the end of the scope of the variable using such memory, but resort to garbage collection.

My question is, when `v1` and `v2` go out of scope, why would it be necessary to free the data buffer twice? Couldn't we just free the data buffer once in addition to "destroying" `v1` and `v2`? I understand that `v1` and `v2` are actually values and not references, but what is the rationale for not making them "smart references" that have the above behavior?

Comment: do you think smart pointer are free to use ? there is a cost so we try to avoid it but in a safe way, so rust have a lot of rule that why there is the move semantic. But if you want you can use a reference counter in Rust too https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html.

Comment: You are free to create a reference by let v2 = &v1 (no overhead). Or to create a Reference counted reference (some overhead). Or to use a copy type (some overhead with String data). Rust allows you to choose what you need (in opposite to languages like Java which almost always chooses the garbage collected reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] what is the rationale for not making them "smart references"?

Performance, mostly. Rust is all about "zero cost abstractions" (a term coined by C++). The language should not incur runtime-overhead if the programmer does not need it. Such "smart references" would be reference-counted pointers (like `Rc` or `Arc` in Rust, or `shared_ptr` in C++) *or* would require a garbage collector. Both of these solutions do have this overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yeah, I guess it's easy to take such smart references forgranted when you aren't really trying to crunch out the last few cycles of performance...

Comment: Oh, sorry, not sure how I missed that. And no, going into more detail here seems definitely out of scope.